# May I turn off PHPSESSID and why it appear on my cookie?

Tags: php, cookies, http-headers

When I check `apache_request_headers()` I found `PHPSESSID`.

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();

foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
    echo "$header: $value <br />\n";
}
```

results something like this.

```
Host: localhost.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: PHPSESSID=ltj5b4tvu9lcpvt9itt3ge4oj6
```

Question :

How do I turn off the `PHPSESSID` and why it's appear on every page by default?

Comment: Are you using PHP's session feature? (`session_start` et al.)

Comment: That's the cookie set by `session_start()`. It's name is `PHPSESSID` unless you change it by calling `session_name("SomeOtherName");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to turn off using cookies in sessions, you can set the PHP ini directive `session.use_cookies` to `0`. See the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-cookies).